# Netbeans - add JPanel to JFrame - issue

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I'm using netbeans, I have created a `JFrame` form with netbeans and it created the following class that I have also edited:

```
public class Gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Gui() {
        initComponents();
        this.setVisible(false);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // finestra al centro dello schermo
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 804, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 536, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                                        
}
```

After that I have created a `JPanel` class that I want to add to previous `Gui` `JFrame`:

```
public class Gui_JTabbedPane extends JPanel {

    public Gui_JTabbedPane() {                      
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JComponent panel1 = makeTextPanel("Try");

        tabbedPane.addTab("Try", panel1, "Does nothing");
        tabbedPane.setMnemonicAt(0, KeyEvent.VK_1);
        add(tabbedPane);
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    }

   protected JComponent makeTextPanel(String text) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
        JLabel filler = new JLabel(text);
        filler.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        panel.add(filler);
        return panel;
    }
}
```

So in my main class I have done this:

```
 Gui_JTabbedPane tabbedpane = new Gui_JTabbedPane();
 Gui gui = new Gui();
 gui.add( tabbedpane );
 gui.setVisible(true);
```

The problem is that it just shows the `JFrame` (Gui) without the `JPanel` ('GuiJTabbedPane`) inside it, as I wanted instead.

Instead if I edit the first class (Gui) removing `initComponents();` the `JFrame` is not shown but this time the `JPanel` does.

How can I solve it **just using/editing those two classes**?

Thanks

Comment: Does `gui.getContentPane().add(tabbedpane); gui.pack(); gui.setVisible(true);` work?

Comment: @Frank Can you comment out the GroupLayout lines in initComponents and let us know the results? Just remove everything but `pack()`. You may have to resize your frame afterwards. I'm betting it's the `GroupLayout` lines.

Comment: @Saviour Self, thanks I think you are right, but netbeans doesn't allow me to edit that code, how can I do that?

Comment: @npinti, I tried your code in my main class but it does not work :/ thanks

Comment: @Frank I am uncertain. I have never used Netbeans. For GUI applications I have always used Window Builder Pro for Eclipse.

Comment: ok I have figured it out. Btw @Saviour Self, your solution works but JFrame is corrupted now and I can't use Netbeans form to work on it, but thanks now I have understood the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either use Netbeans to do all of your GUI or do it by hands. Mixing both often leads to strange behavior as, by default, Netbeans use `GroupLayout` and if you don't also use that layout and do groups with your components in the `Component` made by Netbeans, they might just not show, like you just experienced. Saviour Self got part of the answer as removing the layout of your `Gui` `JFrame` makes everything show fine.

I would suggest you use Netbeans as it's GUI editor is a good one. You can do it by yourself too but that needs more testing generally.

Edit : To add your own `Component` to Netbeans palette, you can go under`Tools`->`Palette`->`Swing Components`, which will open the palette Editor (using netbeans 7.3). From there, click `Add from Project` and select your project, that will show the available components that can be added. Select the ones you want.

Comment: thanks, yes I thought about that, but I think it's useful to use netbeans JFrame to manually insert, move, resize etc... elements, but it is useful to have components to other classes too like my case (see JPanel).

Comment: @Frank Added my comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the GUI editor add a JPanel, and set the property **custom creation code** to:

```
new Gui_JTabbedPane()
```

Now the creation is done in `initComponents` and finally `pack()` is called, which does the layouting.

---

One remark, calling in the constructor an overridable (non-final, non-private) method, `makeTextPanel` is bad style, as it behaves unexpectedly: [why aren't fields initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657877/why-arent-fields-initialized-to-non-default-values-when-a-method-is-run-from-su/17658277#17658277).

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work :/ maybe I need to edit something else

Comment: You did not call `setLayout`. You could try a JPanel form with the GUI editor too. But I see the answer was found.